# Better way of formatting my array and removing ',' and ':' in C#?

Tags: c#

So i'm just wondering if anyone here can suggest a better solution for formatting the data in the string array so that it doesn't contain "," or ":"?

```
    public void formatArrayInformation()
    {
        string[] readTxtFileAsOne = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\test.txt");


        string formatArrayString;



        for (int i = 0; i < readTxtFileAsOne.Length; i++)
        {


            formatArrayString = readTxtFileAsOne[i];
            string removeCommaInString = formatArrayString.Replace(":", " ");
            formatArrayString = removeCommaInString.Replace(",", " ");
            readTxtFileAsOne[i] = formatArrayString;



        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any problem with your approach. I would only simplify it like this:

```
public void formatArrayInformation()
{
    string[] readTxtFileAsOne = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\test.txt");

    for (int i = 0; i < readTxtFileAsOne.Length; i++)
    {
        readTxtFileAsOne[i] = readTxtFileAsOne[i].Replace(":", " ").Replace(",", " ");
    }
}
```

If instead of replacing them with spaces you want to just remove them, you can either, of course, use `""` as the second parameter for the `Replace` method or do something weird like this:

```
public void formatArrayInformation()
{
    string[] readTxtFileAsOne = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\test.txt");

    for (int i = 0; i < readTxtFileAsOne.Length; i++)
    {
        var txt = readTxtFileAsOne[i].ToList();
        txt.RemoveAll(x => ":,".Contains(x));
        readTxtFileAsOne[i] = new string(txt.ToArray());
    }

}
```

Comment: I feel like your solution is the way i would do it more then using multiple extra strings to replace, thank you for the feedback.

Answer (score 1):

You can make it in a single line like

```
string removeCommaInString = formatArrayString.Replace(":", "").Replace(",", "");
```

Comment: This does indeed look better than what i came up with, thank you!

Comment: Actually you don't even need `removeCommaInString`.

Answer (score 0):

Replace it by empty quotes ( replace(",","") or replace(":","") )

```
            formatArrayString = readTxtFileAsOne[i];
            string removeCommaInString = formatArrayString.Replace(":", "");
            formatArrayString = removeCommaInString.Replace(",", "");
            readTxtFileAsOne[i] = formatArrayString;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use Linq:

```
readTxtFileAsOne[i] = new string(readTxtFileAsOne[i]
    .Where(c => !(new[] {',', ':'}).Contains(c)).ToArray());
```

To break it down, one of the constructors of `string` allows you to pass in a character array and construct a string from the array of characters. This is what we are using.

We are breaking the string down into characters and creating a new array, skipping the `,`'s and `:`'s. This new array gets created into a string using the `string` constructor.

Comment: I have the feeling going for this approach is mainly for extreme Linq lovers. Readability and performance (probably not perceivable though) are not among its strengths.